# 500 mW RF amplifier for 170 MHz design

Tags: amplifier, rf, impedance-matching

For a new project I need to build an RF amplifier for continuous-wave with about 500 mW (**27dBm**) output at 170 MHz.

It doesn't need to transport data, it is only for measuring purpose.

The input comes from a signal generator, that can go up to about 15 dBm output, so the amplification needed is about 12 dB. The circuit should run with 5 V supply voltage.

The output of the RF amplifier is directly connected to an antenna, that is matched to 50 Ohm at 170 MHz.

A simple solution without big matching effort would be preferred, as I don't have much RF measuring equipment, only a cheap chinese network analyzer (NanoVNA).

So far I tried some ADL5535, but always when the output comes up to 500mW (14Vpp) they got killed.

The same experience I had with a BFQ790. It was drawing about 500mA, when the output was OK, but then also died.
Heat dissipation should be no problem, as I'm using the PCB (with heat sink compound) of a former destroyed amplifier module for my experiments, see picture[image]

I'd really appreciate some help, how to design a simple circuit, that is more robust against mismatching of the antenna. I know some theoretical basics about T or Pi-Networks, but I'd rather need some practical support.

Maybe someone has an example circuit (with components, that sill are active and available).

Comment: It sounds like you're not adequately dealing with the heat. What does your PCB layout and heatsink look like?

Comment: Do you have a picture of the circuit you are using? It sounds like a heating problem to me as well if the circuit works then dies. RF amplifiers can get pretty hot, especially in such a small package. The max input power into the ADL5535 is 20 dBm, with a P1dB of about 18 dBm so you definitely aren't over driving it.....attaching a picture of the circuit to your question would help us help you

Comment: Your original post didn't sound confident that the antenna is actually matched to 50ohm at 170MHz.  You can confirm the antenna match with your VNA.

Comment: _"I tried some ADL5535, but always when the output comes up to 500mW (14Vpp) they got killed."_ - ADL5535 datasheet says maximum output at 190MHz is 18.9dBm (77mW). Why do you think it can do 500mW?

Comment: The BFQ790 datasheet states that in final stage operating mode (which is what you appear to be doing) the efficiency is 25%; if you tried to run it at 500mW output, then the device will be dissipating 1.5W. With a junction to soldering point thermal resistance of 25K/W at an ambient of 25C you need a thermal resistance from the soldering point to ambient of < 31K/W to keep the junction at 110C or below which from your picture you are unlikely to achieve. Therefore, it looks very much like a thermal management issue.

Comment: @Peter  Many thanks for this detailed answer!! You are right, I missed the 25% efficeiency. 500mW output seems quite too much for this transistor. I'll try a different one...